# How to write a base64 encoded field content coming from Suds to a file in Python 3

Tags: python, encoding, base64, byte, decoding

There are many string to bytes conversion question about Python 3 on Stackoverflow, each one treating slightly different cases, and as I couldn't find this specific one, I'll answer my own question here.

Some fields of a webservice, e.g. those that transport files like a PDF document, may do that base64 encoded.

It Python 2 this did work:

```
with open(filepath, 'w') as file_:
    file_.write(my_content.decode('base64'))
```

Now, in Suds on Python 3 the equivalent would be:

```
from base64 import b64decode
file_.write(b64decode(my_content))
```

But this results in an error: `a bytes-like object is required, not 'Text'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that Suds returns a custom type `Text` which for `b64encode` unexpectedly doesn't react like `str` (altough it's subclassing it). So it must be converted explicitly to `str` first:

```
from base64 import b64decode
file_.write(b64decode(str(my_content)))
```

Comment: No. Your answer throws an exception in my case: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Text'

Comment: `b64decode` returns a `bytes` object, probably you have some other problem in your code.

Comment: Yes, and it expects a bytes object. Did you read my question text?

Comment: It allows an `str` object as well, as long as it only contains ASCII data (which is obvious, given that the base64 charset is a narrow subset of ASCII).

Comment: Most importantly, your error message shows that you are not passing in an `str` object, but an instance of some `Text` class that we know nothing about. If *that* doesn't work is an entirely different problem, and your question should reflect it. There's more than enough confusion on the `byte`/`str` issue without throwing in custom classes in the mix.

Comment: OK, sorry, I can confirm your answer is right. The data I'm converting in the program though throws the error, it comes from a SOAP library (suds) which receives it from a webservice.

Comment: Actually, a file_.write(b64decode(str(my_content))) would have done the job. Should I delete the topic?

Comment: In the original Python 2 version it seems like that `Text` class inherits from Python 2 `unicode`, I don't know about the Python 3 fork. Still, to convert it to a "regular" Python 3 string doing `str(your_text_object)` will probably do. - edit: I was late; yeah, exactly

Comment: Maybe it could be rephrased by talking explicitly about the `studs` `Text` object, writing in the relevant error messages to help search. I expect this to be useful for people rightly surprised by this behavior - especially if `Text` is a subclass of `str`.